# Search through an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, search

can anyone help me with a search through an array in php, please?

$source variable contains an array of numbers, in fact, they are id's of the products currently placed in shopping cart, so the array could have different count of values
for example:

```
$source = array(34,22,25,64,60);
```

$find variable contains a set of numbers which I'm looking for in $source array, there will be for example 12 numbers

```
$find = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);
```

I need to apply this:
build an IF statement to check if the $source array contains at least 3 values from $find array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (count(array_intersect($source, $find)) >= 3)
```

http://php.net/array_intersect